# Unable to import "ExtentHtmlReporter" for the java class

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying generate reports for the selenium test script. but unable import "ExtentHtmlReporter" packages to the class.

[image]

added dependencies as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and extent-config.xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
<configuration>
<!-- report theme --> <!-- standard, dark --> 
<theme>standard</theme>

<!-- document encoding --> <!-- defaults to UTF-8 --> 
<encoding>UTF8</encoding>
    
<!-- protocol for script and stylesheets --> <!-- defaults to https --> 
<protocol>https</protocol>

<!-- title of the document --> 
<documentTitle>ExtentReports 2.0</documentTitle>

<!-- report name - displayed at top-nav --> 
<reportName></reportName>

<!-- report headline - displayed at top-nav, after reportHead- line -->
<reportHeadline>Automation Report</reportHeadline>

<!-- global date format override --> <!-- defaults to yyyy-MM-dd--> 
<dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd</dateFormat>

<!-- global time format override -->
<!-- defaults to HH:mm:ss -->
<timeFormat>HH:mm:ss</timeFormat>

<!-- custom javascript -->
<scripts>
    <![CDATA[ $(document).ready(function() {});]]> 
</scripts>

<!-- custom styles --> 
<styles>
    <![CDATA[]]> 
</styles>
</configuration>
</extentreports>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.extentreports.com/docs/versions/5/java/index.html

> ExtentHtmlReporter, ExtentLoggerReporter The ExtentHtmlReporter and
> ExtentLoggerReporter were deprecated in series 4.1.x and have been
> removed in version 5. The replacement is ExtentSparkReporter, which is
> comprehensive, ports all features along with a host of new ones.

```
ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("Spark.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Need to downgrade the extent report version. downgraded to 4.0.9 and it works for me